# Meteor error not being sent to client

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to send a Meteor.Error to the client in the case where I have a duplicate key.

On the client, the 'error' in the callback is undefined (because at the moment, minimongo can't check for unique key indexes)

On the server the 'error' in the callback correctly throws an exception that a duplicate key exists and so it won't be inserted.  However, the 'Meteor.Error' is never sent to the client.

```
Links.insert({
  link: link_to_add,
  user_id: this.userId
}, function(error, result) {
  if (error != null) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(409, 'Link already added');
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am open to alternatives if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems obvious to me now, but the problem was I wasn't capturing the error in the Meteor.call.

```
Meteor.call('add_link', {
  link: link_to_add,
  tag: tag_to_add
}, function(error, result) {
  // the error is correctly being captured here
  return console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: you'll probably want to make sure the error isn't null before sending it to the console.

Comment: In this case I wanted it to console.log 'null' or 'undefined' while I was trying to see if it would capture it or not.  It's since been cleaned up of course.